# Bad Request Почта России удаление заказа

Tags: api, request, delete

Предварительно отправляю заказ - получаю ID заказа и хочу его сразу удалить по инструкции https://otpravka.pochta.ru/specification#/orders-delete_new_order.

Отправляю следующие данные:

```
$orderData = array
    ('backlog_ids' =>
        array(my_id));
$url = 'https://otpravka-api.pochta.ru/1.0/backlog';
$method = 'DELETE';
$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization: AccessToken ХхххХхХхххХхХХХХХхххххХХХХХХХ',
    'X-User-Authorization: Basic ХхххХхХхххХхХХХХХхххххХХХХХХХ',
];
$data = json_encode([$orderData]);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response =  curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Получаю ответ:

```
{
   "timestamp": "2020-05-01T15:38:45+0300",
   "status": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "message": "Bad Request",
   "path": "/1.0/backlog"
}
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: По какой ссылке?

Comment: Так это естественно, т.к. доступ туда может быть только при правильных данных в "Authorization: AccessToken ХхххХхХхххХхХХХХХхххххХХХХХХХ" и "X-User-Authorization: Basic ХхххХхХхххХхХХХХХхххххХХХХХХХ". Вы эту ссылку смотрели https://otpravka.pochta.ru/specification#/orders-delete_new_order ?

Answer (score 0):

Всё! Разобрался! Просто невнимательно читал документацию.

```
$orderData = 12345678; //нужно было просто вписать номер my_id
```